# My nodemon gives me the message 'restarting due to changes' but when I refresh my browser I don't see the changes applied

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have recently started using nodemon to run node js server. But I am having some trouble using that, it gives me the same experience as If I was using node for that, after every change I have to terminate the process and run the command( nodemon  ) again.
without running that command, when I just save changes to my file, the nodemon logs to the terminal 'restarting due to changes' but when I refresh my browser I don't see the changes applied. [I have an image of my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evcJJ.jpg)

I used pm2 instead but still could not get the problem solved,instead got it more frustrating. With pm2 even  manually restarting the app wasn't showing the changes, I had to run the script in a different port to see the changes.

Comment: You can configure a restart when app crashes. 
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

Answer (score 0):

In your attached image, you are using `nodemon start` to run the server process. Note that in your logs, nodemon output says

```bash
...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js start`
...
```

which means the `start` in `nodemon start` command is being passed in `node server.js start`, which I think isn't required. You can start your server with nodemon using just `nodemon`, or if you want to specifiy the exact command you want to re-run automatically, then create a `nodemon.json` file in your project root folder, and set the following in it.

```json
{
  "exec": "node server.js"
}
```

Then just type `nodemon` in your shell, it should work properly.

Also, in your code, it will be better if you write the `app.listen(2000)` like below

```js
app.listen(2000, ()=>{
    console.log("Running on 2000 now.")
})
```

this output should help you determine when the server has actually started.

After applying all the changes mentioned above, the final output should appear like below

```bash
PS: C:\Users\user\Desktop\EXPRESSJS> nodemon
# some nodemon logs
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Running on 2000 now.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, I got my problem solved by knowing about an awesome feature the nodeJS team added in the releases of node versions 18+ (I think 18.11).
They have provided us with a builtin method, which alternately does the work of nodemon. We just have to update the node version to 18.11 or + , and then in the terminal type:

```
node --watch <file name> //(if you want only the file be watched)
node --watch-path <path> <file name> //(any change in the path will cause the file to run again... if you want a directory to be watched)
```

That got my issue solved.